# Sending selected object from listview on entry unfocused through event to command behavior

Tags: xamarin, eventtocommand

I have a listview, within the list view I have an entry box. I want to run some code after the entry box becomes unfocused which I have got working with the xct event to command behavior, but I would like the command to receive the object from the listview that the entry is inside.

(sudo xaml)

```
<ListView Name = ReportGrid>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout>
                <Entry Text="0.00" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="16" BackgroundColor="White" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0">
                    <Entry.Behaviors
                        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Unfocused" Command="{Binding Source={Reference CountLocationTabView}, Path=BindingContext.QtyEntryUnfocused}" 
                                                          CommandParameter="{Binding Source={Reference ReportGrid}, Path=SelectedItem}" />
                    </Entry.Behaviors>
                </Entry>
            <StackLayout/>
        <ViewCell/>
    <DataTemplate/>
<ListView/>
```

I have seen examples of this where events from the listview are turned into commands but what about the elements within?
thanks in advance.

Comment: `CommandParameter="{Binding .}"`.  Also, the XAML you posted is not valid.  When there are glaring problems in your code like that, it is hard to focus on the problem you actually need help with.

Comment: binding . does not work it sends the unfocused event args which does not contain the object i need. I understand that the xaml is not valid except for the entry I just wanted you to understand that this entry is within a listview template.

Comment: xaml is better now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code,I created a simple demo, and it works properly.

You can refer to the following code:

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding items}" HasUnevenRows="True" HeightRequest="240" x:Name="Listview">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Frame Padding="0" >
                            <Grid Padding="0">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label x:Name="DistNumber" Text="{Binding DistNumber}" FontSize="18"   Grid.Column="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                <Entry  x:Name="CountEntry" Placeholder="Choose Quantity" 
                                        Text="{Binding Count}" 
                                        
                                        Grid.Column="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" >
                                    <Entry.Behaviors>
                                        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior 
                                            EventName="Unfocused" 
                                            Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.EntryUnfocused, Source={x:Reference Listview}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />

                                    </Entry.Behaviors>
                                </Entry>
                               
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

The ViewModel is:

```
 public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<SomeItem> items { get; set; }

    public ICommand EntryUnfocused { get; protected set; }


    public MyViewModel() {

        items = new ObservableCollection<SomeItem>();

        items.Add(new SomeItem { Name = "item1", DistNumber = "1", Count = 1,Quantity = 1 });
        items.Add(new SomeItem { Name = "item2", DistNumber = "2", Count = 2, Quantity = 2 });
        items.Add(new SomeItem { Name = "item3", DistNumber = "3", Count = 3, Quantity = 3 });
        items.Add(new SomeItem { Name = "item4", DistNumber = "4", Count = 4, Quantity = 4 });
        items.Add(new SomeItem { Name = "item5", DistNumber = "5", Count = 5, Quantity = 5 });
        items.Add(new SomeItem { Name = "item6", DistNumber = "6", Count = 6, Quantity = 6 });


        EntryUnfocused = new Command(CompletedCommandExecutedAsync);
    }

    private void CompletedCommandExecutedAsync(Object obj)
    {
        SomeItem item = (SomeItem)obj;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("<----- item Name = " + item.Name + "<-----> item Count = " + item.Count);
    }
}
```